# Passing parameter in URL leads to 404 page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I have tried the code for passing parameter in the URL but the system is considering it as parameter and leads to 404 error page

Below is the code I am using for the same

```
<a href="view_pre_read/1315">click here to go</a>
```

My system's htaccess code is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /dashboard_new4/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

My routes.php has following code: `$route['view_pre_read/(:num)'] = 'view_pre_read/index/$1';`

controller is :

```
class View_pre_read extends CI_Controller {

    function index($tid){
            echo $tid;
            $this->load->view('pages/notopic',$data);

    }

}
```

Please help how to over come this. if i send only controller url like 'view_pre_read/' its  finding the controller class. only thing is if i send parameter its going to 404 error.

Thanks and Regards
raju

Comment: Please check the link format, should be like <a href="<?php echo site_url()?>view_pre_read/1315">click here to go</a> with assumption that url helper has been loaded.

Comment: Try, **<a href="view_pre_read/index/1315">click here to go</a>**

Comment: i have tried that one also

Answer (score 1):

change this to

```
$this->load->view('pages/notopic',$data);
```

$this->load->view('pages/notopic/',$data);
and bingo

Comment: But first of all it is not coming to controller to load the above page

Comment: have you replace index.php from .htaccs file

Comment: do one thing 
$this->load->view('pages/notopic',$data);
change it to
$this->load->view('index.php/pages/notopic',$data);
and check if its working or not then tell me i will give you exact solution

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting "index" i.e. method name in your class.
Try this 
view_pre_read/index

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<a href="view_pre_read/index/1315">click here to go</a>`
instead of `<a href="view_pre_read/1315">click here to go</a>`

The first url segment is class name (view_pre_read) & section one is function (index). The parameter you need to pass in third position.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>/view_pre_read/1315">click here to go</a>
```

Comment: add route name with parameter in this way.if you write route on href in this way.definetely i will work 